# TextView on the right of dynamically created Buttons

Tags: android, imageview

[image]
As seen in the picture, everything works fine except that myTextView, instead of appearing just on the right of the last Button, it does on top of 16, 17 and 18. I can’t manage these 3 Buttons to appear bellow the rest. Here is my essential code, where I create dynamically the Buttons and myTextView:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1); // id del XML
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    LinearLayout fila = new LinearLayout(this);
    fila.setLayoutParams(new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) { 
            if (i==3 && j==3){ 
               TextView myTextView = new TextView(this); 
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=newLinearLayout.LayoutParams(490, 40);
       layoutParams.setMargins(870, 30, 0, 0); 
       myTextView.setTextSize(26);
       myTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
       layout.addView(myTextView);


       break;
   }
      Button btnTag = new Button(this);  //          
      btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
      btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(255, 166)); 
     fila.addView(btnTag);
     btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 5));
     btnTag.setOnClickListener(prueba);
     }
      layout.addView(fila);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I have solved the problem. Instead of a LinearLayout I have to use a RelativeLayout. Like this, I can set the TextView wherever I want on the screen throughout the xml. Here is the code, where with rel_btn I set the Buttons wherever I want, too:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout. activity_main);

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1); // id del XML
for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    switch(i) {
        case 1: rel_btn.leftMargin = 0; rel_btn.topMargin = 0; break;
        case 2: rel_btn.leftMargin = 255; rel_btn.topMargin = 0; break;
        case 3: rel_btn.leftMargin = 510; rel_btn.topMargin = 0; break;
        …… as many as Buttons requiered
    }
    rel_btn.width = 255; rel_btn.height = 165;
    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
    btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
    btnTag.setId(0+i); // les pone el ID
    btnTag.setOnClickListener(prueba);
    layout.addView(btnTag);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to attach a picture as a proof of what I have done, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Set layout weight sum

```
fila.setWeightSum(5);
```

**2.** Set width = 0dp and weight = 1 for all buttons

```
btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 166, weight));
```

**3.** Set width=0dp and weight = 2 for textview

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);
layoutParams.weight = 2;
//layoutParams.setMargins(870, 30, 0, 0);
myTextView.setTextSize(26);
myTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**Updated onCreate method**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1); // id del XML
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    int width = 0; //0dp, we will use weight to set width
    int weight = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        LinearLayout fila = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, weight);
        fila.setLayoutParams(params);
        fila.setWeightSum(5);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (i==3 && j==3){
                TextView myTextView = new TextView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40);
                layoutParams.weight = 2;
                //layoutParams.setMargins(870, 30, 0, 0);
                myTextView.setTextSize(26);
                myTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                layout.addView(myTextView);
                break;
            }
            Button btnTag = new Button(this);  //
            btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 166, weight));
            fila.addView(btnTag);
            btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 5));
            btnTag.setOnClickListener(prueba);
        }
        layout.addView(fila);
    }

}
```

Comment: user12345, have you tried it? May be I’m doing something wrong but it doesn’t work for me now. Like this, even the Buttons don’t appear, myTextView either. Will you be able to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Try replacing 0 with MATCH_PARENT

Comment: Sorry, but how to write MATCH_PARENT dynamically?

Comment: ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

Comment: Error: Not a statement

Comment: You need to import ViewGroup class using import android.view.ViewGroup;

Comment: Where do I have to write "ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;" because the Error continues? Sorry.

Comment: I am updating the answer for you ease.

Comment: You should up vote answers posted by others as well.

Comment: user12345, where is your promise of updating your answer?

Comment: I did. I had replaced 0 with ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

Comment: Sorry, I thought you would write it in a different place than the previous one. However, the problem continues, even a little worse. I wanted to send an image here, but I can't.